# CSS filter brightness makes gridlines vanish

Tags: css

I have a table with two CSS brightness filters applied:

```
#MyTable tr:nth-child(even)
{
  filter: brightness(85%);
}
#MyTable td:nth-child(even) 
{
    filter: brightness(85%);
}
```

to clearly delineate rows and columns when individual cells can vary in background colour.

But the black gridlines (borders) are behaving very oddly.

In Firefox (51):

The right and bottom gridlines of all filtered cells are replaced with the background colour. White cells keep their gridlines.  The behaviour is the same whether filters are applied to rows, columns or both.

In Chrome (56):

If I apply just the first filter, which alternates row brightness, then the top gridline and left gridline of coloured cells in even rows become the same colour as the background. White cells keep their gridlines.

If I apply just the second filter, which alternates column brightness, everything works fine.

If I apply both filters, the top and left gridlines of coloured cells in even rows but odd columns become the same colour as the background. Again, white cells, cells which are in even columns (i.e. have a filter), or cells which are in odd rows (i.e. don't have a filter), keep their black gridlines.

This also happens if I select even rows using a class instead of tr:nth-child(even).

What is causing this, and how do I fix it?

Edit - minimal working example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        #MyTable {
            border-spacing: 0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        #MyTable td {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        #MyTable tr:nth-child(even)
        {
            filter: brightness(85%);
        }
        #MyTable td:nth-child(even) 
        {
            filter: brightness(85%);
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="MyTable">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: red;">A</td>
                <td style="background-color: red;">B</td>
                <td style="background-color: red;">C</td>
                <td style="background-color: red;">D</td>
                <td style="background-color: red;">E</td>
                <td style="background-color: red;">F</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: red;">A</td>
                <td style="background-color: red;">B</td>
                <td style="background-color: red;">C</td>
                <td style="background-color: red;">D</td>
                <td>E</td>
                <td style="background-color: red;">F</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: red;">A</td>
                <td style="background-color: red;">B</td>
                <td style="background-color: red;">C</td>
                <td style="background-color: red;">D</td>
                <td style="background-color: red;">E</td>
                <td style="background-color: red;">F</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm definitely not sure what's going on, or what even ought to be happening according to the spec. It might be undefined behavior.

I did notice that the rule `border-collapse: separate` will prevent the borders from disappearing.

```css
#MyTable {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: seperate;
}
#MyTable td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#MyTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  filter: brightness(85%);
}
#MyTable td:nth-child(even) {
  filter: brightness(85%);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table id="MyTable">
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: red;">A</td>
      <td style="background-color: red;">B</td>
      <td style="background-color: red;">C</td>
      <td style="background-color: red;">D</td>
      <td style="background-color: red;">E</td>
      <td style="background-color: red;">F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: red;">A</td>
      <td style="background-color: red;">B</td>
      <td style="background-color: red;">C</td>
      <td style="background-color: red;">D</td>
      <td>E</td>
      <td style="background-color: red;">F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: red;">A</td>
      <td style="background-color: red;">B</td>
      <td style="background-color: red;">C</td>
      <td style="background-color: red;">D</td>
      <td style="background-color: red;">E</td>
      <td style="background-color: red;">F</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've added a MWE, hope that clears things up.
By 'black gridlines are behaving oddly', I meant 'I am using border collapse, and displaying black lines of 1px thickness between all rows and columns, such as you might see in a traditional printed grid. These black lines sometimes change colour to match the new cell background colour, as detailed.'

Comment: Thanks, I've modified my answer/workaround. The `transform` rule on the `<tr>` definitely doesn't play nice with the `border-collapse` rule